# Convert to JS normal code after complied the code to deploy?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm following NodeJS Tutorial on Udemy
When I run `npm run build` for Frontend Code, I got my normal code changed to this code

```
(this["webpackJsonpnode-complete-social-network-prep"]=this["webpackJsonpnode-complete-social-network-prep"]||[]).push([[0],[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,function(t,e,a){},,,function(t,e,a){t.exports=a(43)},,,,,function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},,,function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){},function(t,e,a){"use strict";a.r(e);var n=a(0),o=a.n(n),s=a(6),i=a.n(s),r=a(47),l=(a(22),a(48)),d=a(15),c=a(46),h=a(49);a(23);var m=t=>o.a.createElement(n.Fragment,null,o.a.createElement("header",{className:"main-header"},t.header),t.mobileNav,o.a.createElement("main",
```

How can I convert it to the normal code?

Comment: This is minified code. `npm run build` is normally done when you are done working on the code and are ready to deploy it to production. Its the same code that you wrote in your editor just spaces removed and names shortened to save space. Check out a [Beautifier](http://minifycode.com/javascript-beautifier/) if you want to see what it looks like without the spaces removed.

Comment: Use development mode, not the production build, if you want to try your unminified code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is minified.
Try using a tool like https://beautifier.io/ to beautify it.